# python pint celsius units

Tags: python, pint

I can't define degC as a unit.

After entering

```
import pint
u=pint.UnitRegistry()
```

When stating `1*u.degC` it outputs `1 degree_Celsius`. Seems that it's OK.

When I'm stating `2*u.degC` it outputs following error...

```
>>> 2*u.degC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\Lib\site-packages\pint\facets\plain\unit.py", line 147, in __mul__
    return self._REGISTRY.Quantity(1, self._units) * other
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
  File "\Lib\site-packages\pint\facets\plain\quantity.py", line 1010, in __mul__
    return self._mul_div(other, operator.mul)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Lib\site-packages\pint\facets\plain\quantity.py", line 103, in wrapped
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Lib\site-packages\pint\facets\plain\quantity.py", line 77, in wrapped
    result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Lib\site-packages\pint\facets\plain\quantity.py", line 958, in _mul_div
    raise OffsetUnitCalculusError(self._units, getattr(other, "units", ""))
pint.errors.OffsetUnitCalculusError: Ambiguous operation with offset unit (degree_Celsius). See https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/nonmult.html for guidance.
```

Could someone guide me why it's like this?

I did read documentation and some searches in browser.
Unfortunately no progress to direction of solution.

Expectation:

1. To use degC unit definition in Python with multiple magnitude meanings, not only with 1.
2. Make calculations using degC unit alias.

Comment: Can someone show a example how to make calculations using pint library and celsius degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that temperature degrees are "non-multiplicative". Which makes sense, you can have a weight and double it, but to say that one temperature is some proportion of another doesn't work, unless you're talking about Kelvin, which where 2 degrees might suggest twice as much of something as 1 degree (but I'm no physicist so take that with a grain of salt).

This portion of the documentation shows how to define a temperature and convert between units:

```
>>> from pint import UnitRegistry
>>> ureg = UnitRegistry()
>>> ureg.default_format = '.3f'
>>> Q_ = ureg.Quantity
>>> home = Q_(25.4, ureg.degC)
>>> print(home.to('degF'))
77.720 degree_Fahrenheit
```

This will let you define different temperatures.

In your case it would look like

```
>>> Q_(2, u.degC)
<Quantity(2, 'degree_Celsius')>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "make calculations using degC alias" but if you'd rephrase the question with a more specific task, I'd be happy to help with that as well.

Comment: The non-multiplicativity of `degC` is specific to that unit, not temperatures as a whole. `2 * degK` works fine.

Comment: I'll update the answer, I suppose with Kelvin being relative to some physical property it makes sense there. degF gets the same error.

Comment: Both Celsius and Kelvin are related to the same physical property, and are identical modulo labelling. It's the fact that Kelvin starts at 0 that allows multiplication to make sense.

Comment: (Mathematically, this is about *torsors*. See https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html, especially the final paragraph. Celsius temperatures form a torsor over the real numbers, which does not define a notion of multiplication. Kelvin temperatures are a trivial torsor over the reals, isomorphic to the reals themselves, so you *can* multiply a Kelvin temperature by a real number. Or a positive real, anyway; even `pint` doesn't stop you from writing `(-4) * degK`.)

Comment: chepner, should I just take out everything between "Which" and "salt)"? I don't want to mislead people.